# Getting value from a 16-bit register

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit, bit-shift, cpu-registers, bit-fields

I have a 16-bit register

- At bit 0 the value is 0
- At bit 1...2 the value is 3
- At bit 3 the values is 1
- At bit 4 the value is 1

So in the end the written value in my register is 30 because:

```
(0 x 1) + (3 x 2) + (1 x 8) + (1 x 16) = 30
```

Now I want to do reverse to get which value is written in the bits:

```
(30 & 1) / 1 = 0  
(30 & 2) / 2 = 1 (this is wrong, it should be 3)  
(30 & 8) / 8 = 1  
(30 & 16) / 16 = 1
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(30 & 2) / 2 = 1 (this is wrong, it should be 3)
```

This is wrong. To get 2 bits you must and with 3 shifted by its bit position. In this case you `and` with `3 << 1 = 6`

```
(30 & 6) / 2 = 3
```

Comment: Hm.... and what if i have the the same situation, but there is also some value in bit 9. Then in this case the value in register is 1054. Bit 9..10 hold value 2.

Comment: so just shifted 3 by 9 bits. Write the bits down on paper and you'll see. In general to get n bits at position m and it with `((1 << n) - 1) << m`

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the exactly what I needed.